# Symfony handleRequest() not matching POST data

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Recently just got back into a Symfony (2.3.10) project. I used composer to updated all packages and I have noticed a strange issue in regards to `form->handleRequest($request)`

```
$recipe = $query->getQuery(); 
$form = $this->createForm('recipe', $recipe); 
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

This form had been setup to add/remove items from a collection i.e like the `tag` example:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

As far as I can tell this was working as expected before the update. The POST data does not include the items I have removed, so it's correct. When the `$request` is passed into the form handler, though, the `$form->getData()` still lists all the items of the collection.

Previously it had removed them as expected.

I have Googled around and hit a dead end, for the moment I loop through the POST data to work out what to remove from the collection, i.e :

```
foreach ($originalRecipeTags as $key => $toCheck) {
    if (isset($postTags[$toCheck->getRecipeTagId()]) ) {
        unset($originalRecipeTags[$key]);
    } else {
        $recipe->removeRecipeTag($recipeTag);
        $em->remove($recipeTag);
    }
}
```

*I was wondering if anyone has come across this issue? Is it a known bug?* Any help would be amazing as I'm not really satisfied with the current solution.

Comment: To what version of symfony did you upgraded?

Comment: Hi, As far as I can tell I upgraded twice this month, in my vendor/symfony/symfony I have the CHANGELOG-2.2 & 2.3, composer is set to "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*", The debug console shows version 2.3.10. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug introduced in `2.3.10`: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10256

Comment: Thank you Jakub, I will keep an eye out for the fix.